# Control-C Causes Typing to Disappear When Using Bash Key Bindings

Tags: bash

I am using the bash shell.
Every time the user presses the enter key, I want to execute a program
that gets passed the command line as an argument.
I successfully accomplished this using the solution below.  My problem is that when I interrupt a program (i.e. tail -f file) by hitting Control-C, I no longer see the characters that I type) until I type "stty echo".

Please recommend either:

- A solution to the disappearing typing problem (and an explanation of why 
  it is happening).
- A different way of accomplishing my original goal that doesn't have this 
  problem

Thank you

```
func1()
{
    # execute the binary named "my_command", passing the command line as
    # an argument.
    my_command "$READLINE_LINE"
}

# Bind my_command to the key sequence Ctrl-h1
bind -x '"\C-h1":func1'

# Bind bash's "accept-line" function, which usually gets called when
# the enter key is pressed, to the Ctrl-h2 key sequence.
bind '"\C-h2": accept-line'

# Make Ctrl-m (Enter key) call my_command with the command line as 
# an argument, followed by accept-line to execute the command line
bind '"\C-m":"\C-h1\C-h2"'
```

Comment: Your question is slightly short of meeting the requirements for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Will you please provide a concrete example of `my_command` and `$READLINE_LINE` when this problem happens?

Comment: The readline library turns echoing off while it is reading a line. Killing the child process interrupts the input; I suppose readline doesn't get a chance to restore the terminal settings. You could try trapping sigchld, maybe.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  @Leon - my_command happens to be a custom program that I wrote, and I showed it this way to justify why I am doing the key bindings (so I can have my_command get access to the command line, stored in READLINE_LINE, each time I hit enter.)  If you substitute "ls" for my_command "$READLINE_LINE", run the code above, and then use ctrl-c to interrupt a program, i.e. tail -f file, the "disappearing text" problem still happens.

Comment: It seems that the problem only occurs if `func1` involves starting a subprocess. For example, if `my_command` is the builtin `echo` command there is no such issue. However, if it is made to run in a subshell, the issue reappers.